# Plugin para alterar a imagem do perfil personalizado

Tags: html5, css3

Existe algum plugin que de esse efeito + modal para trocar foto ?
Ou é tudo feito no *CSS* :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom deve até existir, mas  para que se limitar a plugins que geralmente podem  dar um monte de pau que você não vai conseguir resolver, se você pode criar seu proprio usando css e jquery ?

Comment: Da para fazer exatamente como nessa imagem só com CSS tranquilamente. Depois basta programar as ações do "enviar" e "remover". Resumindo, o design é tranquilo só com CSS, já o back não sei te dizer qual seria a melhor opção, mas certamente php resolve a parte do back. Se quiser um modelo de CSS similar fala ai

Comment: @hugocsl gostaria de um modelo sim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um modelo básico como falei. Com CSS é bem tranquilo de fazer não precisa de plugin ou biblioteca...

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.avatar::after {
    opacity: 0;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f040";
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 92px;
    height: 92px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
}
.avatar:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.avatar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    top: 60%;
    left: 60%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
}
.box input {
    display: none;
}
.box input:checked + div.menu {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="box">
    <label class="avatar" for="btn">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"> <span>upload</span></i></a>
        <br>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit"> <span>edite</span></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```